# What’s your recommendation for implementing a single authentication system across two websites with download analytics?

Tags: authentication, analytics, two-factor-authentication

So here is the total workflow. I use S3 buckets to store large SDK files (10-500 MB), a Freshdesk instance to let customers raise tickets and ReadTheDocs for general documentation. Right now all of them have separate authentication system, i.e. different user/passwords. I need to implement something which allows users to have a single pair of credentials. The authentication system should also have the abilities to block certain domains (essentially any non-customers). I also need to know who is logging in and what files they are downloading, at what time, etc.

I am absolutely beginner at this . I heard about SSO, but let’s days if we use Google, people don’t always use Google for work.

I also considered some other ideas like sending user an email with a link to log-in which is valid for say a day. The email has to be on a pre-approved list of emails. For downloads, I thought of sending out an email that lists the file being downloaded, downloader name and a 6 digit code.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Are you looking for a library or framework (if so, for which language) – or for something else (if so, for what)?

Comment: SSO doesn't mean Google or any other specific service. You can implement your own SSO.